# Birthdays from given array is sorted wrong in the output

Tags: php, html

I've got a file that reads birthdays from the database and shows upcoming birthdays for users. But it seems like the sorting is completely wrong, can someone give me a tip where it goes wrong? It shows only day and month and it seems like its sorting by day instead of the month.

I tried multiple sorting options but can't get it right.

the usort function, was a test to get it right, but it does nothing.

```php
if ($birthdays) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach($birthdays as $item {
        $item->birthdate = str_replace('/', '-', $item->birthdate);
        $time = strtotime($item->birthdate);
        $time = date('d.m', $time);
        usort($item->birthdate, function ($a, $b) {
            return substr($b, -3) - substr($a, -3);
        });

        $date = "<span class='time-created right'>{$time}</span>";
        echo "<a href='{$item->profileURL()}'><li><img src='{$item->iconURL()->topbar}' /><i class='fa fa-birthday-cake'></i>{$item->fullname}{$date}</li></a>";
    }

    echo "</ul>";
}
```

The Output is as following:
27.07
25.07
24.07
18.08
16.11

But it should be like this:
24.07
25.07
27.07
18.08
16.11

Comment: _“It shows only day and month”_ - of course it does, that’s what the `d.m` part in `$time = date('d.m', $time);` _means_ …

Comment: Yea that was more like an unnecessary hint, sorry about that i can't edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Put the month before the day and you can sort it normally. Meaning 0105 for fifth of January, and 1025 for October 25th.

```
$arr = ["0727", "0725", "0724", "0818", "1116"];

sort($arr);
var_dump($arr);
```

Gives:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "0724"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "0725"
  [2]=>
  string(4) "0727"
  [3]=>
  string(4) "0818"
  [4]=>
  string(4) "1116"
}
```

No fancy sorting is needed